# unlock user account using UNBoundID SDK

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, jndi, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am trying to unlock the AD account using UNBoundID, but i am unable to succeed on it. can anyone please help me on this.?

One of my try as below,

```
    byte[] quotedPasswordBytes=null;
    final String quotedPassword = '"' + flag + '"';
    try {
    quotedPasswordBytes = quotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Modification mod=new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed",quotedPasswordBytes);
    ModifyRequest modifyRequest= new ModifyRequest(userDn, mod);
    /*ModifyRequest mr = new ModifyRequest(userDn, 
    [new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "msDS-UserAccountDisabled", "TRUE".bytes)]);*/
    connection.modify(modifyRequest);
```

FYI,

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the userAccountControl attribute instead.  The trick is to know what value to set it to.

- 512   Enabled Account
- 514   Disabled Account
- 544   Enabled, Password Not Required
- 546   Disabled, Password Not Required
- 66048     Enabled, Password Doesn't Expire
- 66050     Disabled, Password Doesn't Expire
- 66080     Enabled, Password Doesn't Expire & Not Required
- 66082     Disabled, Password Doesn't Expire & Not Required

Reference http://www.netvision.com/ad_useraccountcontrol.php or http://rajnishbhatia19.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/active-directory-useraccountcontrol.html or google for codes.

```
    try {
        Modification mod = new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE,"userAccountControl","512");
        ModifyRequest mr = new ModifyRequest(userdn,mod);

        LDAPResult lr = ldapcon.modify(mr);
        ResultCode rc = lr.getResultCode();
        if (!rc.equals(ResultCode.SUCCESS)) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong enabling the account for "+userdn);
        }
    } catch (LDAPException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since this was asked, but the attribute to change is lockoutTime, which should be 0 to unlock